# PostgreSQL sorted Nested Datas

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I want to sort data on a table which, for some of them are nested.

Table is a BOM structure. A product BOM can be composed by a component and other BOM. What I need, is to have for a Product BOM with the base components and all the components which composed the subsidiary BOM:

```
id     product_id    bom_id
1             10          
2             20          1
3             21          1
4             20         
5             30          4
```

What I want will look like this:

```
component_id   bom_product_id
21             10
30             10 
30             20
```

Sorry for the design of these tables.

Comment: Is `(component_id,bom_product_id) = (30,10)` a typo? Shouldn't that be `(20,10)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your question.
I think datas in table are right. Because if i want to know all components of the BOM with ID 10 it will be product with ID 21 and 30.Any help?
Thank you again,
N.

Comment: Not enough info in the question and unclear what you are asking.
Maybe you could post DDL?